# UNC FileShare Authentication for WCF Web Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, .net-3.5

We have a WCF Service which will Upload and Download Documents to and from FileShare respectively.

The client application will pass a FileShareLocation and FileName inthe request.
But we are getting some exception, and not able to get the response.

FileSharePath sample : `\\SERVERIP\SHAREDFOLDER`

> Note: The service is working fine when I don't use Network File Share.

```
'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---



Server stack trace: 

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)



Exception rethrown at [0]: 

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

   at wcfServiceTest.wcfService.ICommonService.UploadDocument(UploadDocumentRequest request)

   at wcfServiceTest.wcfService.CommonServiceClient.wcfServiceTest.wcfService.ICommonService.UploadDocument(UploadDocumentRequest request) in D:\Test\CMS\wcfServiceTest\wcfServiceTest\Service References\wcfService\Reference.cs:line 2309

   at wcfServiceTest.wcfService.CommonServiceClient.UploadDocument(RequestHeader UploadDocumentReqHdr, Byte[]& UploadDocumentContent) in D:\Test\CMS\wcfServiceTest\wcfServiceTest\Service References\wcfService\Reference.cs:line 2316

   at wcfServiceTest.frmMain.DocumentUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Test\CMS\wcfServiceTest\wcfServiceTest\frmMain.cs:line 105
```

Comment: sorry, I was in quite hurry

Comment: Now you show the client error. Your service gets an error, debug or log and analyze that.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by myself.

1. Create a new Application pool in IIS
2. Change Identity of AppPool to the User who has access to FileShare
3. Change the WCF Service Application Pool to the new Application Pool